# How to cast with different types

Tags: c#, class, casting

Here is my code:

```
public class MyButton
{
  Object button;

  public MyButton(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton button)
  {
    this.button = button;
  }

  public MyButton(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton button)
  {
    this.button = button;
  }

  public void EnableButton(bool enable)
  {
    if (button is System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton)
      ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton)button).Enabled = enable;
    else if (button is System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton)
      ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton)button).Enabled = enable;
  }

  //...
}
```

I was wondering can I make this code shorter? Can I cast it by its type somehow? Something like this:

```
public void EnableButton(bool enable)
{
  ((FakeFuctionToGetCastType(button))button).Enabled = enable;
}
```

Of course its my fake function... So is there a way to do so?

Comment: Any time you check a type and then immediately cast it you could just use `as` instead, and it would shorten your code, but as several of the answers have demonstrated, you should really make a more fundamental design change to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it generic:

```
public class MyButton<T> where T : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem
{
    T button;

    public MyButton(T button) 
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void EnableButton(bool enable)
    {
        this.button.Enabled = enable;
    }
}
```

*Edit: As a side note, you'll want the constraint to be as tight as possible in the assignment of the generic. If you can find a common inherited class for the controls you want to use that is closer than `Control` then you should use that one.*

Comment: How do I create ant object of this class? for example with System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton object

Comment: How do you mean? Are you asking how to instantiate this generic class with your button object?

Comment: Oh... I ma getting error:
The type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'App.MyButton<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Comment: @user1836922: Yah, the control is not really what you want. If you look in my note, I mention that T should be constrained by the closest possible type that will accept both. Looking at their MSDN docs, it looks like the closest class they both inherit is `ToolStripItem`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the `is` operator so I assume that `ToolStripButton` and `ToolStripSplitButton` extend `Button` .Thus `Enabled` is a property defined in the base class Button.So, Enabled will be called polymorphically , if the actual type is `ToolStripButton`, then its `Enabled` will be called.
So this should be enough

```
  Button button;
  button.Enabled=enable;
```

or

```
 this.Enabled=enable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Enabled property is on the base class `Button` (it probably is), you don't need to cast. Just do this:

```
public class Button
{
  Control button;

  public Button(Control button)
  {
    this.button = button;
  }

  public void EnableButton(bool enable)
  {
    button.Enabled = enable;
  }

  //...
}
```

If the Enabled property is not on the `Button` base class you can do this:

```
((dynamic)Button).Enabled = enable;
```

Comment: `dynamic`...eww.  Because actually figuring out how to design a program properly might take work, just don't bother...

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this;

```
public class Button
{
   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem button;

  public MyButton(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem button)
  {
    this.button = button;
  }

  public void EnableButton(bool enable)
  {
    button.Enable = enable;
  }

  //...
}
```